# What is the "Overrun Bonus" for military units in CivWorld?

Tags: civworld

In a CivWorld battle, units can get various bonuses that increase their strength (Heroic stance and Weather effects are two that are explained on the wiki).

I saw a battle today where units had a 2x **Overrun Bonus**.  How do you get this bonus?

Comment: Is the advantage different in CivWorld from other civs? In the old ones, overrun meant that you would win a battle without any risk to the attacker, and you'd get it when you had a high enough advantage (7x stronger or so)

Comment: It's probably related conceptually, but the way units are deployed and battles happen in CivWorld is utterly unlike previous Civ games so it's not entirely clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overrun is granted to melee units on the battlefield when there aren't any melee units on the other side to oppose them.  Similarly, mobile units get Flanking, ranged units get Bombardment, and naval units get Blockade when they are completely unopposed.